# LWC Flow Control - Finish throws exception

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, exception, flow-screen-component, flowsupport

**THE CONTEXT:**

I am creating an LWC as a screen flow element. The LWC is very simple, it displays in a radio button group all of the existing Opportunity record types.

Once the user selects a record type and clicks on create, the next step of the flow is executed. On the other hand, if he clicks on cancel, the flow finishes.

To control the flow's 'navigation', I have imported the FlowNavigationNextEvent and FlowNavigationFinishEvent from the 'lightning/flowSupport' module.

**THE PROBLEM:**

The flow navigation NEXT event works just fine. **The problem** is with the flow navigation FINISH event which when fired, throws a script error:

[image]

**THE CODE:**

JS file:

```
import { api,track, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {FlowNavigationNextEvent,FlowNavigationFinishEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
import getAvailableRecordTypes from 
'@salesforce/apex/el_GeneralUtilities.getAvailableRecordTypes';
export default class El_OpportunityQuickCreation extends LightningElement {
@api selectedId = '';
@api objectName;
@track hasError=false;


_options;
get options() {
    return this._options;
}
set options(val){
    this._options=val;
}


connectedCallback(){

    let options=[];
    //1.Call an Apex method to retrieve all the available record types of the object that was passed in as input
    //2.Initialize the radio group element with the returned available record types
    getAvailableRecordTypes({objectName:this.objectName})
        .then((recordTypes)=>{
            recordTypes.forEach(recordType=>{
                options.push({label:recordType.Name, value:recordType.Id})
            });
            this.options=options;
        })
        .catch((error)=>console.error(error));
}

//Capture the user's selection in the selectedId variable which is also this screen_flow component's output
handleChange(event) {
    console.log()
    this.selectedId=event.detail.value;                                     
    this.hasError=false;
}

flowFinish(){
    const navigateFinishEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
    try{
        console.log(navigateFinishEvent);
        this.dispatchEvent(navigateFinishEvent);
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.error('Exception: '+ex);
    }
    
}

flowNext(){
    if(this.selectedId=='')
        this.hasError=true;
    else{
        const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
        this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
    }
}
closeQuickAction() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
}
```

}

HTML file:

```
<template>
<template if:true={hasError}>
    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-alert_error" role="alert">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">error</span>
        <lightning-icon size="small" icon-name="utility:error" style='float:left!important' alternative-text="Error!" title="Error"></lightning-icon>
        <h2> You need to select a record type
        </h2>
      </div>
</template>

<lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
                      options={options}
                      value={value}
                      onchange={handleChange}
                      type="radio"
                      >
</lightning-radio-group>

<div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
    <hr/>

    <!-- Button group: simple buttons -->
    <lightning-button-group class="slds-float_right">
        <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={flowFinish}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="Create" variant="brand" onclick={flowNext} icon-name="utility:record_create"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-button-group>
</div>
<br/>
<br/></template>
```

**THE QUESTION**
Why does the flow navigation next event work, whereas the flow finish event doesn't?

Comment: Is `flowFinish()` called by the cancel button's `onclick`? Have you checked there's no typo in the html?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves The answer is yes, I believe there is not typo. I edited my post with the html code, thank you. If you see something wrong with it please tell!